# .NET to VBA wrapper

Tags: .net, vba, interop

I have a set of classes in .NET dll, which i need to use in VBA. The problem that some memebers are declared as nullable, so i have to make a wrapper for these classes, which i can use in VBA. There are about 20 classes, so I am looking for some tool or technique to make it automatic, any ideas?

And reatted question - when i have this wrapper ready - is there some simple way to copy objects like:

```
For each [class member] of MyClass
    MyNewClass([class member])=MyClass([class member])
next
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using VBA, you're using COM Interop.  In general it's considered good practice to explicitly define the COM interface, i.e. instead of:

```
[ComVisible]
public class MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

you should use:

```
[ComVisible]
public interface IMyClass
{
    ...
}

[ComVisible]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Once you do this, it's easy: you just need to avoid nullable types in the `IMyClass` interface, and implement it explicitly, e.g.:

```
[ComVisible]
public interface IMyClass
{
    ...
    public int MyInt {get; }
}

[ComVisible]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    ...
    public int? MyInt {get; }

    int IMyClass.MyInt
    {
        get { return this.MyInt ?? 0; }
    }
}
```

Incidentally another benefit of using explicit interface implementation in this way is that you can log exceptions before propagating to the COM Interop client, and get the useful stack trace information which is lost when exceptions are propagated to COM. E.g.

```
[ComVisible]
public interface IMyClass
{
    ...
    public void MyMethod();
}

[ComVisible]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    ...
    public void MyMethod()
    {
    }

    void IMyClass.MyMethod()
    {
        try
        {
            this.MyMethod();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ... log exception ex here ...
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach that might fit the problem is to use Microsoft's T4. Available in CS 2010 and I believe better in 2012. If using 2010 use the free version of tangible T4 Editor.

20 does not sound like a lot of classes. Perhaps hand coding may be faster, but T4 offers an approach to auto-generate your API which would pay dividends if the source classes change.